# How to include/exclude components of Angular2 app to build multiple versions?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, package.json

I have an Angular2 project. I need to build two versions out of it, where one version will contain all the components created while other version will not contain every component. By default, everything created under `src` folder is included in the project.

Answer (score 1):

In [tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)

You can use the "include" and "exclude" properties.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way I can configure to effect include/exclude depending on version I want to build? Or should I manually exclude/include each time I need to build a different version?